# Oracle Data Conversion: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Error while converting varchar2 column value to Number
i am unable to compare varchar2 value field with another value 
like this '10:54' with '11.00', i have to compare minutes with minutes field.
How is it possible?

Query is:

```
select 
adm_emp_num,adm_emp_nam,adm_ace_dte,asm_sft,asm_ed_tme,asm_st_tme,adm_ace_tme from Adm,asm
where adm_ace_dte =ass_sft_dte
and to_char(adm_ace_dte,'YYYYMM')=201409
--having min(to_char(adm_ace_tme,'HH24:MI')) < asm_st_tme
having min(to_char(adm_ace_tme,'HH24:MI')) < to_char(to_number(asm_st_tme,'99999
9.99'),'999999.99')
group by adm_emp_num,adm_emp_nam,adm_ace_dte,asm_sft,asm_ed_tme,asm_
st_tme,adm_ace_tme
order by 1,2
```

refer the table structures in the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5861972

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your entire query please?

Comment: select 
adm_emp_num,adm_emp_nam,adm_ace_dte,asm_sft,asm_ed_tme,asm_st_tme,adm_ace_tme from Adm,asm
where adm_ace_dte =ass_sft_dte
and to_char(adm_ace_dte,'YYYYMM')=201409
--having min(to_char(adm_ace_tme,'HH24:MI')) < asm_st_tme
having min(to_char(adm_ace_tme,'HH24:MI')) < to_char(to_number(asm_st_tme,'99999
9.99'),'999999.99')
group by adm_emp_num,adm_emp_nam,adm_ace_dte,asm_sft,asm_ed_tme,asm_
st_tme,adm_ace_tme
order by 1,2

refer the table structures in the link::http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5861972

Comment: @Manu - Please put your query in your qestion. Posting it in comment section makes it unreadable. Don't forget to put your query as a code and not as a plain text!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`EXTRATC` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) to get minute part. Examples:

- from `TIMESTAMP` type:

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
  ```
- from `DATE` type:

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM DUAL;
  ```
- from `VARCHAR2` type (for example: `11:30`):

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('11:30', 'HH24:MI')) FROM DUAL;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('12:56', 'hh24:mi'), 'mi')) from dual;
```

i.e. first convert your string to a valid `date`, then extract the `minute` part (by specifying just `'mi'` in the format), then casting that to a number.

You can then perform comparisons:

```
...where to_number(to_char(to_date('12:56', 'hh24:mi'), 'mi')) = ...
```

You could of course just parse out the substring, but you would then be vulnerable to invalid minutes, like 79.

Comment: ok, but i have to add 10 minutes to the minute side
i mean i have to compare the coming time of employee with the fixed time (in the column value) + 00:10 (for the tolerant time)
ie. he can come between (09:00 Am to 09:10 AM) but if exceeds i want his name on my report.

Answer (score 0):

You can substring your value and convert it to number, for example:

```
...
WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('10:54',4,2)) >= TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('11:00',4,2));
--for minutes

...
WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('10:54',1,2)) >= TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('11:00',1,2));
--for hours
```

Comment: Well, you didn't post your table structure and sample data, so I suggested an answer on hard values and not the ones from some table... EDIT: ok, I'll take a look at your edit and try to provide an answer